# While loop to read interger values from standard input

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, scanf

I need my program to read integer values into adjacent elements in the array, and set the counter to the total number of integers read.  I also need another loop to print the values to the screen.

How do I go about doing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int numArray[100];
    int counter, value;

    printf("Enter array length \n");
    scanf("%d", &counter); 

    int i = 0;
    while(i < counter) {
        scanf("%d", &numArray[i]);
        value = numArray[i];
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are the numbers input? One per line, or separated by spaces, or something else?

Comment: How will you define the end of input?

Comment: You use two uninitialised variables, `i` and `counter`. Variables are not initialised to 0 in C. Then what should `counter` mean if not the number of elements read? Your call to `scanf` can return one of three values: 1 for success, 0 for failure and `EOF` for end of file.

Comment: I had no clue if that was the way to write it. I can also use a txt file to read in values but Im lost on that as well

Comment: Do you want each digit of the number to go to each of the array indices? what's it that you want?

Comment: I just need to know how to read values into a array using a while loop

Comment: Fix the existing problems, before moving on. You can't make something work based on something not working. Garbage in - garbage out.

Comment: Is this better? and can you help me with the next loop. @EugeneSh.

Comment: The next loop is to print the values? Just like the first loop with `printf("%d\n", numArray[i]);` inside. Don't forget to reset `i`. Or use `for` loop.

Comment: what do you mean reset I? like re declare as 0? @EugeneSh.

Comment: this is what I did but it prints different values `int x = 0;
 while(x < counter){

  printf("Values: %d\n", numArray[i]);
  x++;
 }` @EugeneSh.

Comment: How the input numbers are separated? Spaces? Newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need my program to read integer values into adjacent elements in the array, and set the counter to the total number of integers read. I also need another loop to print the values to the screen.
>
> How do I go about doing this?

The overall program should work, however you need to initialize:

```
value = 0; /*Initialize Variables */
counter = 0;
```

In C when you enter a function like main variables like value and counter get initialized with random value -- if you don't initialize. It could cause you problems.

```
 while(i < counter) /*Scans the values into the array */
 {
   scanf("%d", &numArray[i]);
   value = numArray[i];
   i++;
 }
```

The scanf function here scans the value you entered into the array.
I'm not sure what you would use values for; your array stores the values for you. However, it could make your code shorter if you use it in a different way.

A loop to print the values would look similar to your original loop.

```
while(i < counter)
{
  printf("%d", &numArray[i]); /*Prints the values in the array */
  i++;
}
```